# jssor slider's arrows gets wrongly positioned

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

So, I tried to implement jssor slider from the documentation provided here [Jssor Documentation](http://www.jssor.com/development/)

I was able to implement it on the go. The problem that I faced is when I moved all the CSS from jssor slider's HTML document to a separate CSS files, the arrow keys stucked at the top with only 50% visibility. I have made sure that every CSS code was copied and pasted very well.
I cannot actually show a fiddle or my code for the same. It is too long. I think **jssor** himself will know the problem, waiting on you jssor.

**EDITED**

Ok, to be more specific, the CSS part that causes this to happen is `height` of `#slider1_container`. I mean everything looked fine until I moved this CSS property from HTML document to a separate CSS file. Why is this happening? The slider I am working on is: **carousel-slider**

Comment: It would be hard to give you a specific answer if there is no code to examine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use class name to specify css for the 'outer contianer'.

```
<style>
.slider1_container {
}
</style>
<div id="slider1_container" class="slider1_container" ...>
```

Comment: Thar worked perfectly fine! I was assigning style to id.